# Can you construct a baby brownian motion from a brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

By a baby brownian motion, I mean a brownian motion $X_t$, $t \in [0,1]$. We can construct a brownian motion on $[0,\infty)$ as
\begin{align}
Y_t = (1+t)X_\frac{t}{1+t} - t X_1, t \in [0, \infty)
\end{align}
But can we also construct a baby brownian motion from a brownian motion?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct from"?  If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, then the restriction of $W_t$ to $[0,1]$ is a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$

Comment: It was in regard to whether existence of a continous BM is equivalent to existence of a continous baby BM. Since you can construct a BM from a baby BM then it holds oneway and I wondered if it hold the other way. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Okay, so just taking the restriction to $[0,1]$ answers your question?

Comment: Yes, it makes good sense. Thanks

Comment: @Brutus : where is that idea from ? I don't think it is as simple as restricting $Y$ to $[0,1]$ to get an $X$ that satisfies the equation. I have also tried two ways of checking that $Y$ is in fact a BM. Not done yet. Somehow intriguing.

Comment: @KurtG. : The baby BM doest have to satisfy the equation it just have to satisfy the definition of a BM i.e. (Gaussian, EX_t = 0, and Cov(X_t,X_s)=min(s,t)). If the BM satisfy this on [0, infty) is must also on [0,1], I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is interesting and not just a matter of restricting the
given BM $Y$ to $[0,1]\,.$ There is rather a relation to the concept of
[Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge).

1. Before dealing with this I'd like to verify first that given the "baby" BM $X$
   on $[0,1]$ the process $Y_t$ defined by

$$\tag{1}
Y_t=(1+t)X_{\textstyle \frac{t}{1+t}}-tX_1
$$
is a BM on $[0,\infty)$ because this was not so obvious to me first. (Clearly, $X$
is the restriction to $[0,1]$ of some BM on $[0,\infty)$ but that is not the point at all.)

From the known property
$$
\mathbb E[X_tX_s]=\min(t,s)
$$
of Brownian motions it follows easily that
$$
\mathbb E[Y_tY_s]=\min(t,s)
$$
holds. It is then relatively straightforward to see that $Y$ is a Gaussian process with Gaussian and independent increments that have variance $\mathbb E[(Y_t-Y_s)^2]=t-s\,.$ Therefore $Y$ is a BM.

2. Relation with Brownian bridge. Using the variable transformation
   $$
   s=\frac{t}{1+t}\,,\quad t=\frac{s}{1-s}
   $$
   one can write (1) as
   \begin{align}
   Y_{\textstyle \frac{s}{1-s}}=\frac{X_s-sX_1}{1-s}
   \end{align}
   so that
   $$
   B_s=(1-s)Y_{\textstyle \frac{s}{1-s}}=X_s-sX_1
   $$ is a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) on [0,1]. That is, a Gaussian process with expectation zero, $B_0=B_1=0$ almost surely, and
   $$
   E[B_tB_s]=\min(t,s)-ts\,.
   $$
3. Construction of $X$ from $Y$. Let's now forget how the BM $Y_t$ was constructed from $X\,.$
   The question is: given a BM $Y_t$ on $[0,\infty)$ does there exist a
   BM $X_t$ on $[0,1]$ such that (1)
   holds for all $t\ge 0\,$? The answer is yes: in the link it is mentioned that
   $$
   B_s=(1-s)Y_{\textstyle\frac{s}{1-s}}\,,\quad s\in[0,1]\,.
   $$
   is a Brownian bridge. Next, with a Gaussian r.v. $Z$ that is independent of $B$ we obtain a BM $X$ on $[0,1]$ by
   $$
   X_s=B_s+sZ
   $$
   which will satisfy
   $$
   B_s=X_s-sX_1\,.
   $$
   Thus
   $$
   (1-s)Y_{\textstyle\frac{s}{1-s}}=X_s-sX_1\,.
   $$
   Transforming $s$ back to $t$ yields (1).